# Enforce field uniqueness to parent in many-to-one relation

Tags: django, django-models

I have a `Table` model which is many-to-one with a `Restaurant` model. Is there a way to have a field `reference_label` in the `Table` model that must be unique **per restaurant**, but not across different restaurants?

In short, I want to enforce `reference_label` uniqueness for tables with the same foreign key.

I know I can just use the `Table`'s `id`, but I want each restaurant to be able to customize how they label their tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    ...

class Table(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reference_label = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['restaurant', 'reference_label']
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Django 2.2 you can use `UniqueConstraint` instead of `unique_together` like this:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['restaurant', 'reference_label'], name='give_it_some_name')
    ]
```

As the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together) state:

> Use UniqueConstraint with the constraints option instead.
>
> UniqueConstraint provides more functionality than unique_together. unique_together may be deprecated in the future.